# In a spring-boot application, is it possible to change the dependency injection by external configuration?

Tags: spring-boot

I am building an application to send email but I want to turn off the actual send and just have it output to a log file in non-prod environments.  The class that actually sends mail is a Spring injected dependency, so my thought was just to build a no-op implementation to swap out with the actual implementation.

Second requirement, I don't want to create separate builds for different environments.  I want to create one and promote it through dev -> test -> prod.

This seems like a common use case for dependency injection but I don't see how to externally configure it.  If I want to do it this way do I need to abandon annotation based injection and use xml instead?

Comment: Not an answer, but your scenario is exactly why environment based builds are essential. I would not consider your approach, personally. Your problem is already solved if you just build per environment. If you're managing your source control correctly, it is just a build (CI) solution and dead simple, generally.

Comment: I disagree with Gregg. One of the fundamentals of Continuous Delivery is building the binary once and using it for testing and deploying to various environments. Configuration should be externalized, making this trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `@Profile("PRODUCTION")` on your production `@Bean` and `@Profile("!PRODUCTION")` on your non-production `@Bean`. Then you can specify the active profile(s) at runtime:

`java -jar bootApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=PRODUCTION, ...`